# How to Ignore Hidden Items in beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

in beautifulsoup4 I used to write:

```
soup.find_all(string=True)
```

But this caused me some problems, how can I ignore items which have `@visibility='hidden'` attribute or `@hidden` attribute.

Comment: Get all items and later filter list and skip elements with `visibility` or `hidden`. OR you may use [function](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) in `find_all` to check if element has some value and skip it. Read all [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to learn all functions

Comment: @furas I already know the filter function but it can't detect that. each element has only 2 attributes from what I can see; parent and text...

Comment: if they don't have attribuets in tag then they may have it in css and you can't catch it with `beautifulsoup`

Comment: BTW: you should say it in question - we can't read in your mind. Better show URL for this page. It may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and JavaScript to detect elements which have CSS with so `visibility` or `hidden`

Comment: Can you confirm the url, or alternatively post the full page html?